# how to set "Program Files" & "Program Files (x86)" in CLASSPATH in Windows

Tags: java, windows-7, classpath

I ran into this issue while setting up CLASSPATH for my tomcat. I need to refer 2 of my installations in my tomcat's CLASSPATH. One of them is at `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4`, and the other one is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\pgJDBC`.
Setting it directly or within quotes doesn't work.

Can you please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Some how I figured this out.
We can simply set C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\9.4 for Program Files folder (just use Progra~1)  and for Program Files (x86) folder set it as C:\Progra~2\PostgreSQL\pgJDBC (just use Progra~2).

Comment: sometimes your server might not allow shortcuts and the command does not work on such case.